# XAP Caching in Silverlight OOB, when using Prism

Tags: silverlight, prism, silverlight-oob

I have a `Silverlight Out Of Browser` Application built using `Prism Framework`. I am using `WebClient` to download the application module `XAPs` depending on the user logged in to the application.

Now my Question is will these other `XAPs` which I am downloading explicitly be cached when running `OOB`.

If yes where will it be cached, and how can I check for updates like `CheckAndDownloadUpdateAsync` which I can use only for the main installed `XAP`.